# Unconditional programming - Cannot use If, Else, or Switch

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm programming Minesweeper -- I've done it, but now my task has changed. I can't use `If-Else` or `Switch`. Do you have some advice on how this code fragment can be rewritten?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        if (bombs[i][j])
                System.out.print("* ");
        else
                System.out.print(". ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java)?

Comment: `System.out.print(bombs[i][j] ? "* " : ". ");`

Comment: No, I can't. Becouse it's like a short IF ELSE operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ternary operator:

```
String result = (bombs[i][j]) ? "* " : ". ";
System.out.println(result);
```

You could also throw in a `while` loop in there:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            while (bombs[i][j]) { System.out.print("* "); break; }     //Will execute once if the statement holds
            while (!bombs[i][j]) { System.out.print(". "); break; } // Same here.
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is what I need.

Comment: `"It is what I need"` Surprised with disbelief. Cannot comprehend why would OP want to do something like that.

Comment: @user3182349 / OP Just to clarify for everyone else, is the `while` loop logic the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Trobbins It makes lesser sense if this is a school requirement and they expect new learners to use `while` instead if `if`? OP must quit that school as soon as possible if that is the case. Nothing againsth npinti's solution, I am just surprised by this bizarre homework requirement.

Comment: @user3437460 Could just be a brain teaser, relax. I think it's a fun problem, forces students to see what other methods of conditional logic there are.

Comment: @Trobbins Even if it is a brain teaser, it must be at least technically correct in terms of usage.

Comment: @user3437460: I see nothing wrong with providing these kinds of assignments, provided that the students are told which ones they should go for in most real world scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ternary operator instead of the `if`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++) {
        System.out.println(bombs[i][j] ? "* " : ". ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One could turn bomb[i][j], a boolean, into an index 0 or 1 to pick `.` or `*`.

```
boolean bomb[][] = new boolean[M][N];
final String emptyBomb = ".*";
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        int index = Boolean.compare(bombs[i][j], false); // 0 or 1
        System.out.print(emptyBomb.charAt(index));
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

As you see, boolean-to-int is a bit of a hack - there is no cast in java.

Comment: You can use a `Map<Boolean, String>` of `false => ". ", true => "* "`